# Likelihood test ratio for discrete random variables

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Just would like to know whether the following statement is true or not:

For a discrete random variable, the numerator of the likelihood ratio test (which is a supremum on a set) is equal to the maximum likelihood of the sample for the null hypothesis.

Please provide a counter example if false. I, unsuccessfully, tried proving that the supremum is the maximum by proving that the parameter set will be compact for a discrete random variable.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is no. To see why, let's look at a simple example. Suppose the proportion of people with red hair among a population is $\theta\in [0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$. Let $\Theta_0=\Big\{\frac{1}{n}\Big\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}.$ We perform the hypothesis test $H_0:\theta \in \Theta_0$ versus $H_a:\theta \notin \Theta_0$ by taking a SRS of size $n=5$ from our population. Suppose that, among our sample of five individuals, we observe nobody with red hair. Our likelihood function becomes $\mathcal{L}(\theta)=(1-\theta)^5$. Notice $\max_{\theta \in \Theta_0}\mathcal{L}(\theta)$ does not exist whereas $\sup_{\theta \in \Theta_0}\mathcal{L}(\theta)=1$